# I want to change the background color of image on hover

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Here is my [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/e6c0y1sk/):

```
.member-img img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
.member-img:hover img {
  background-color: rgba(71, 161, 215, 0.5);
}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work.

I want to change the background color of image on hover

It would be best to keep the html like it is since it's part of a wordpress project.

.

**Update:** 
Thanks for all the help but none of this solution are what I really need.

Anyway since it's not working to put a hover on the image, will it be possible to create another div that will stay exacly on top of the rounded image and will have a transparent color background?

Comment: You cannot change images background color using CSS

Comment: http://jsbin.com/jufulig/1/edit?html,css,output — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Quentin this is OP's fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/e6c0y1sk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to create another div with a transparent background-color on top of that image.

```
.hover {
    border-radius: 50%; /* same rounded shape */
    width: 210px;   /* with the same with and height */
    height: 210px;
    display: none;  /* we can make it display: block with js */
    position: absolute;
    top: -210px; /* position it exactly on the top of the image */
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(71, 161, 215, 0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the background of the image, which is the div the image is in, then:

```
     .member-img:hover {
        background-color: rgba(71, 161, 215, 0.5);
    }
```

would be the answer.

Comment: No, I need only the image to change background color.

Comment: @Light_Warrior your question makes no sense. An image is an image. If you understand the technical limitation than you should make your ideas a bit more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that for img but you can do that:-

```css
    .member-img {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background:  url('https://dummyimage.com/300') center center no-repeat;
       
    }
    .member-img:hover {
      background: rgba(71, 161, 215, 0.5);
    }
```

```html
    <div class="member">
      <div class="member-img">
          <!--img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" alt="" -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: When hovered over, you are technically hiding the image.

Comment: yes, when hover is active img is hide. If you need have visible img and and some style (like opacity, blur or grayscale) you can try use filter property

Comment: thank you, but I just need to use an image that already exists and is not transparent. Please check my update maybe we can find another solution

Answer (score 0):

your sample image does not have a transparent background, if you use a transparent image like as google logo, it works as you want on hover:

```css
.member-img img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 60%; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*background-color: red; */ /*just for test */
}
.member-img:hover img {
  background-color: rgba(71, 161, 215, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="member">
  <div class="member-img">
      <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png" alt="" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not complete sure about what you exactly want. If you want the background to change color when hovering over it, try this in you css:

```
img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

.member-img:hover { background: rgba(71, 161, 215, 0.5);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this:-

```css
.member-img img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
   
}
.member-img:hover{
  background-color: rgba(71, 161, 215, 0.5);
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div class="member">
  <div class="member-img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" alt="" >
  </div>
</div>
```

or

```css
.member-img img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
   
}
.member-img:hover{
  background-color: rgba(71, 161, 215, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="member">
  <div class="member-img">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300" alt="" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not change background-color of image but you can make use [css filters](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp). Filters make your image some effects like blur,saturated.